# Do I need to use normal python in addition to pyspark or pyspark has everything I need?

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, pyspark, cloudera

My company is switching to using Hadoop & spark for machine learning. I know python is very comprehensive in libraries, but when we switch to pyspark, what if we need something that is not available in pyspark yet? Also, it might be easier to keep using python because I already know python.So:

1. Can I run my normal python code in spark and still get all the benefits like speed?
2. Do people use only pyspark or they also use normal python together with pyspark?
3. Can you mix them together and write part of the code in python and part of it in pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

`Pyspark` is more or less a library of functions that you can use on top of python.

1. You will still be able to run your python codes, they won't benefit from `spark` though (since you won't be using the `pyspark` libraries, objects...)
2. The objects you will be manipulating are pyspark objects (`RDD`, `dataframes`, `datasets`), therefore you won't be able to mix operations just like you can't mix `pandas` with other things. You will be able to use python to create UDFs (User Defined Functions) that you can then apply to each row of your `RDD`, `dataframe` (just like `map` in `pandas`)
3. There are ways to convert your pyspark object into other python objects (`list`, `pandas dataframe`, `json`...) when it is small enough to bring it to the driver's memory.

Comment: I think a key point to highlight is that Pyspark is a Python [binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding).

Comment: Thank you. Right now if my boss asks me to do a data science project, I will probably need to use both python and spark, but I have no idea which part should be done with python and which part with spark. Most of the courses online teach either python or spark, but not both of them together in an actual project . So:

1- In what scenarios do I use python in addition to spark? ( as you mentioned we can create UDFs to use in mapping of spark). What else?

2-Where can I find sample code that uses both python and pyspark to complete an actual data science project?

Comment: Spark is a tool for big data. Python libraries will be more powerful for specific things such as machine learning, text mining ... you can check out this example https://mapr.com/blog/churn-prediction-pyspark-using-mllib-and-ml-packages/ if you want to understand how to build your ML project from feature extraction to a final model. Data science is too broad a term to give you a definite answer.